# Deploy Mercurial Changes to Website Hosting Account

Tags: linux, bash, version-control, mercurial

I want to move only the website files changed since the published revision to a hosting account using SSH or FTP. The hosting account is Linux based but does have have any version control installed, so I can't simply do an update there, and the solution must run on the local development machines.

I'm essentially trying to do what http://www.deployhq.com/ does, but for free. I want to publish changes without having to re-upload everything or manually choose the files to move. I'm open to simply using a bash script that compares versions and copies each file (how? not that great with bash) since we'll be using Linux for development, but something with a web interface would be nice.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you know which revision was last pushed to the production server, you can do something like `hg log -v -r 10:tip` (replacing "10" with the correct revision ID), and parse the `files:` lines in the output, then just upload the files that show up there.

Comment: Thanks @Wobble! Could you help me with a script that would copy each file over ssh without having to do it manually?

Comment: Who owns the Mercurial server? Do you have any control over the repository configuration? Have you thought about using hooks?

Comment: @j0k - It's on bitbucket.org.

Comment: Something that would run in the command line might be nice too. Then I could write a simple php/mysql web app to keep track of the deployed revision number and generate the commands to deploy the latest revision.

Comment: @j0k Also, bitbucket can POST to a callback URL, but I don't think that helps any since the hosting account doesn't have Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

This seems more like a job for [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) than one for hg, given that that target doesn't have hg installed.

Something like so:

```
rsync -avz /path/to/local/files/ remote_host:/remote/path/
```

This would transfer all files, recursively (-r), from .../local/files/ and place them in /remote/path. The -az compresses and perserves file attributes.

rsync takes care of only transferring files that have changed.  Be sure to watch for trailing slashed when specifying source paths, they matter (see the link above).

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention - the hosting company claims I can't do rsync even with SSH access since it's not installed on the server.

Comment: I haven't used rsync much, but the hosting company's response puzzled me. I thought I should still be able to sync to the server even if I couldn't run rsync from the server. Would you be able to elaborate on this?

Comment: Have you tried it? I think it should work over ssh. See what the error is if it doesn't.

Comment: If *rsync* isn't available on the remote site, you could mount the webspace to a local directory, e.g. using [curlftps](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/), and then use rsync "locally".